# Prevent user from resizing columns with WPF ListView

Tags: wpf, gridview, listview

How can I prevent a user from resizing GridViewColumns withing a ListView control?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

i found a solution and probably it will help someone else someday ;)

you have to override the GridViewColumnHeader's ControlTemplate (default template is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788747.aspx) ) and remove the **PART_HeaderGripper** from the template in order to prevent resizing of your columns.

there is another solution that comes up with subclassing GridViewColumn described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/atc_avalon_team/archive/2006/04/11/573037.aspx). for representation purposes i prefer xaml only solutions though

Comment: First solution is better for the usability point of view, since the user simply cannot change the width. With the second option, the user sees a cursor that suggests he can resize the column, but it doesn't resize.

Comment: The problem of the first approach: there is no visual separator between adjacent columns.

Comment: The best solution I've found is to set IsEnabled=false for that Thumb.

Comment: To use the first solution (overriding ControlTemplate), copy `GridViewColumnHeaderGripper`, `GridViewColumnHeader`, and the colors into your Resources. Change the first line of the `GridViewColumnHeader` style to be `<Style x:Key="GridViewColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">`. Finally, apply it to your GridView by doing `<ListView.View><GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewColumnHeaderStyle}">...`

Comment: Also, it seems like the linked MS style is a little wonky. Aside from the `Key` and `TargetType` being reversed in the `GridViewColumnHeader` style, the header is colorized a gradient of purple.

Comment: Pakman, if you're still around, why do you include GridViewColumnHeaderGripper if you're ripping out the PART_HeaderGripper element? Shouldn't you just replace <Thumb x:Name="PART_HeaderGriper" /> with <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="1" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />?

Comment: What I ended up doing to make the column widths unchanged-able and to preserve the vertical dividers between the columns in the header is copy GridViewColumnHeader default style and changed the name, as Pakman states. I did not copy GridViewColumnHeaderGripper, it's no longer required. I replaced <Thumb x:Name="PART_HeaderGripper /> element with <Line Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" X1="0" Y1="0" X2="0" Y2="18" />

Comment: Actually, replacing <Thumb x:Name="PART_HeaderGripper /> element with <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness=".5,1" /> works/looks better.

Comment: Do not remove Gripper. Just set `IsHitTestVisible` to `False` in `GridViewColumnHeader` 's Template! `<Thumb x:Name="PART_HeaderGripper" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>` . In this way user will see the gripper, but is not allowed to resize the column.

Answer (score 35):

For those looking for a quicker and simpler answer.

Set IsEnabled to False in the ColumnHeaderContainerStyle. This will prevent the user from resizing.

Like this:

```
<GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
       <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
  </Style>
</GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
```

If you want to fix the disabled grayed out color add a trigger on the IsEnabled property and fix what you need.

```
<GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
       <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
       <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">                
          <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="Black"/>                       
       </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
```

This answer might not be as elegant as other posted; but in my case all I needed was a quick way of doing it.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Both this and InTheZone's answer are good, but if you need the column headers to be clickable for sorting etc., they won't work.

Answer (score 32):

Darkonekt's answer is good, however it may be preferable to set `IsHitTestVisible` to false instead of `IsEnabled`. This has the benefit of not greying out the headers.

```
<GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}}" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
    </Style>
</GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
```

Comment: What about using a keyboard for resizing then?

Comment: this disables also the scrolling

Answer (score 0):

A smooth solution:

```
<GridViewColumn ...>
    <GridViewColumn.HeaderContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">
            <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
        </Style>
    </GridViewColumn.HeaderContainerStyle>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: this disabled scrolling and does not work well with keybobard resizing.... also this is a duplicate answer.... @InTheZone already proposed the exact same code

Answer (score -2):

I was able to do something similar with the instructions in this post

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/atc_avalon_team/fixed-width-column-in-listview-a-column-that-cannot-be-resized)

I wasn't able to use a full XAML solution, since I was building everything in my code behind due to the dynamics of it. Worked great on the first try.