# WPF sizable grid column

Tags: c#, wpf

I have downloaded the source code and using this logview to view log4net logs.

In my previous post evanb removed this link 
http://yourlog4netviewer.codeplex.com/

which made other user to think my question was not complete and moderator casperone closed it.

Here is my question again.

The Message column in this logviewer is not resizable. I have modified this source code and set Message column width as Auto but still the Message column is not resizable.

below is the snippet

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Message" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Message}" />
```

when I set width as 100 then the message column is fixed 100 width

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Message" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Message}" />
```

when I set width as auto then the message column width is width of the message length. I am not able to resize the message column on runtime.

Could some one help me how to make this message column resizable.

Thanks,

Esen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GridViewColumns are resizable by default. It's actually quite hard to make them not resizable :D

[Prevent user from resizing columns with WPF ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181956/prevent-user-from-resizing-columns-with-wpf-listview)

That question shows some methods of implementing a non-resizing grid. It's probably a template that has been changed, you should look in XAML files to see if the template is being set anywhere.