# WPF GridViewColumnHeader fixed width

Tags: wpf, styles

a little background first. We have some legacy UI controls which are defined in text files and we are parsing the same text files to create *xaml*.

One of the controls is similar to a WPF *ListView* and the text file can hold a collection of columns which have their own properties. One of these properties denotes if a column is to have a fixed width, which WPF does not automatically provide.

A picture speaks a thousand words, so here is an example of a parsed file containing a *ListView* with four columns:

[image: Basic layout]

For simplicities sake I have used coloring for demonstration purposes. The first column with the *red* text, is the column with a fixed width.

To achieve this, during the parsing, each *GridViewColumnHeader* receives a *Style*, which in itself can be modified, depending on the flags (i.e. "IsFixed") contained in the properties for that column.

In order to fix the width of a column, I have created a *Style* which adds the *MinWidth* and *MaxWidth* setters to the style.  Please note that the *ColumnResize* is a custom enum.

```
private void _ModifyColumnResize(ref Style style, ColumnResize columnResize, int width)
{
    if (columnResize == ColumnResize.IsFixed)
    {
        var minWidth = new Setter(MinWidthProperty, (double)width);
        var maxWidth = new Setter(MaxWidthProperty, (double)width);
        var fixedColor = new Setter(ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Red);

        style.Setters.Add(minWidth);
        style.Setters.Add(maxWidth);
        style.Setters.Add(fixedColor);
    }
}
```

This all seems to work fine, double-clicking on the column grip does not automatically change the width to that of its content (as with the other three columns). The problem is if I click on the gripper then attempt to resize, then I see this:

[image: After resizing]

As you can see, the column itself has the same width, but to the left and right of the column, spacing appears - which is not wished.

My question is, can I stop this behavior through styling? Ideally I would not like to have the gripper visible for a column which is not to allow resizing, but I am unsure as to how to accomplish that as the *Style* would be created in code-behind (during the parsing) and not in *xaml*.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You said 'Ideally I would not like to have the gripper visible for a column which is not to allow resizing'. Wanted to know what operations a user is allowed to perform on Column headers in your app?

Comment: Hi there, they are supposed to be able to sort and reassign the column layout (drag&drop) which I don't see as being a problem. The problem - for now - is that in the old controls, they were able to say that a column had a fixed width hence the question. Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181956/prevent-user-from-resizing-columns-with-wpf-listview). As per your scenario, I think you need to modify the Column header control template. We cannot disable header since the user will interact with header for other things (sort/drag/drop)

Comment: For setting this custom style for header in your parser, you can define required style in application resources and set it the ColumnHeaderContainerStyle property of control. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686917/setting-the-style-property-of-a-wpf-label-in-code) link may help.

Comment: With your help I have found a way to do this. I'm just going to clean up then write the answer here shortly with credit going to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to @DareToExplore here is the solution:

I grabbed a copy of the default template for the *GridViewColumnHeader* from MSDN and removed the part *PART_HeaderGripper*. This Style is **not** to be the default for every column and is only to be used for a column which should not be resizable.

Whilst parsing the text file, for every column which may be resized, nothing happens, as this is the default behavior.

For the non-resizable column, I grab the Style resource from the *App.xaml*, then assign that Style to the *HeaderContainerStyle* property of that *GridViewColumnHeader* like this:

```
if (parsedColumn.ColumnResize == ColumnResize.IsFixed)
{
    var style = this.FindResource("GridViewColumnHeader_NoResize");
    gridViewColumn.HeaderContainerStyle = style as Style;
}
```

For now, I will leave the Style in the *App.xaml* and grab it as needed.

I hope this is detailed enough and it helps someone along the way.

Thanks again @DareToExplore!

Comment: Glad that I could help. You can accept this as your answer.

Comment: Apparently, I need to wait until tomorrow to accept this so I will wait a day! I do hope you get credit for this, thank you once again.

Comment: Ok. Credit- Well your 'thank you' is a credit for me. In terms of the stackflow points credit, I don't think any points will be credited. That is because I did not post an answer, which you could accept. I just guided you. I am not sure, if you can up vote by comments and that would add something.

Comment: As someone who is fairly new to WPF could you please post the appropriate resource xaml?